# can't import name 'CommentForm

Tags: python, django, import

```
python
ImportError at /post/5/comment/
cannot import name 'CommentForm'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/post/5/comment/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name 'CommentForm'
Exception Location: E:\pywork\djangogirls\blog\views.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  E:\Python35\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.0
Python Path:    
['E:\\pywork\\djangogirls',
 'E:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django_debug_toolbar-1.4-py3.5.egg',
 'E:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages\\sqlparse-0.1.19-py3.5.egg',
 'E:\\Python35\\python35.zip',
 'E:\\Python35\\DLLs',
 'E:\\Python35\\lib',
 'E:\\Python35',
 'E:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 16 Jun 2016 17:02:11 +0800
```

when I study this course
https://github.com/DjangoGirls/tutorial-extensions/blob/master/homework_create_more_models/README.md . 
run this url

http://localhost:8000/post/5/comment/
I get this error.

How to fix this?

===========================================

This is my /blog/view.py file

```
python
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from datetime import datetime
    from .models import Post
    from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm
    from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


....

def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail',pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request,'blog/add_comment_to_post.html',{'form' : form})
```

Comment: http://imgchr.com/images/QQ20160617152512.png

Comment: do you have `CommentForm` c;ass in the `/blog/forms.py` file? Can you try `import bolg.forms` in the python shell to check that `forms.py` have no syntax errors

Comment: Thank u very much,I check the code again and add the CommentForm class ,It works now.But I don't know how to choose your answer to be the best.